# Inline Functions - Automatic inline

Tags: c++, function, inline

When a short function is defined inside a class declaration, it is automatically made into an inline function.

My questions are,

1. How short the function should be for automatically in-lining ? Is there any line-limit for that?
2. Is there any way to know that a function is automatically in-lined ?

Comment: 1) ask your compiler, 2) check the machine code.

Comment: inline is just a hint to the compiler which compiler may or may not follow

Comment: Any function defined within the class definition is automatically declared inline. The length of the function's body doesn't matter for that. Whether the function will actually be inlined in the generated machine code, is an entirely separate and largely unrelated question .

Comment: This is a very detailed thread on inline functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726337/inline-functions-automatic-inline

Comment: You should not care. Leave the inlining decision to the compiler. When optimization is enabled, it will make a better choice than you'll be able to do.

Comment: @Raza you linked to this page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. How short the function should be for automatically in-lining ? Is
>      there any line-limit for that?

There is no hard limit (or more precisely yes, we can find upper limit on a given system but you won't find it specified anywhere). The compiler tries to predict what the advantages of this process given particular circumstances might be. If the compiler decides that inlining the function will make the code slower, or unacceptably larger, it will not inline it. It won't do it also if it simply cannot do it because of a syntactical dependency, such as other code using a function pointer for callbacks, or exporting the function externally as in a dynamic/static code library. Remember also that marking function `inline` is only expressing a wish, compiler is not obliged to do this.
In C, any function with internal linkage can be inlined, but a function with external linkage is subject to restriction.

> 2. Is there any way to know that a function is automatically in-lined ?

You can disassemble the binary and you will see if there is an call to a function or if it is **in line**.

[Do inline functions improve performance?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-and-perf.html)

[Inline Functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc07cplr243.htm)